# Pass Boolean through classes

Tags: actionscript-3, variables, boolean

I am fairly new to AS3 and I want to know how to set a boolean to true or false in one package class and have it do something in another package class.

This is where I first set my boolean "mute":

```
    package 
{


public class AvoiderGame extends MovieClip 
{
            public var mute:Boolean;

    public function Game() 
    {

        mute = false;
```

And I want to change it on this package and have it effect the first package where I originally put it:

```
package 
{
public class DocumentClass extends MovieClip 
{

    public function onRequestMute( navigationEvent:NavigationEvent ):void
    {
                 mute = true; 
    }
```

I know it should be fairly easy but I'm not that great in certain parts of as3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make it a static variable. you need to refer to it as "AvoiderGame.mute" everywhere not inside of the owning class.

```
//declaration in AvoiderGame 
public static var mute:Boolean;

//use in some other file
AvoiderGame.mute = (true | false);
```

This is considered a bad practice overall though. I suggest looking up how to make a simple sound manager class to take care of this type of global variable.

Try searching for: "sound manager as3", "singleton pattern as3"

Comment: You never declared `mute` as `static`.

Comment: quite the oversight...  fixed now.

Comment: Hmm doesn't seem to work. Edit: Nevermind, Got it to work! Thanks!